# 'git rebase -i > reword' revert my files back to the state before commit

Tags: git

Have anyone ever experienced this:

After editing a commit message via `git rebase -i` > `reword`, despite this command [shouldn't modify any contents](https://help.github.com/articles/interactive-rebase#reword), some files revert back to it's original state before committing and git can't detect any difference between those files and files in the local repository.

- `git status` said "nothing to commit, working directory clean"
- tried to `push` the commit to github and `pull` it back, but the files still doesn't follow up with the repositories

Editing the file, and use git `git checkout -- <filename>` does somehow solved this problem.

But I'm still curious whether this is a bug or I did something wrong.

**git version 1.8.4.msysgit.0 @ Windows 7x64**

Comment: Can you do `git rebase --continue`

Comment: I've used msysgit on Windows 7 for a year (including the 1.8.x versions), and I've never experienced the problem you are describing with the `reword` operation during an interactive rebase.